# Creating a spectral histogram of an input Image

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, fft, noise-reduction

I am trying to create a **spectral histogram of a single input image** in Python.

Meaning a histogram that captures the spacial frequencies in the image, and present their found distribution in the image.

For example, for an image with one value (e.g. all black) we expect a high value at the DC (zero) frequency, and nothing else.

The bigger picture is that I have a noise reduction algorithm which acts as a smoothness filter over the image.
I can see visually that it creates a "smoother-less-detailed" image but I want to capture it graphically with a histogram that can demonstrate that higher frequencies were truly filtered out of the image using the algorithm.

I've started with **FFT transformation** over the image, and was soon not sure how to derive such histogram in a correct way.

An example of what I've started playing around with is the following code:

```
import scipy.fftpack as fp

im2freq = lambda data: fp.rfft(
    fp.rfft(data, axis=0),
    axis=1)

hist, bins = np.histogram(im2freq(X)) ### X is a numpy image in 3xWxH dims
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used an implementation inspired by [this blog](https://www.astrobetter.com/blog/2010/03/03/fourier-transforms-of-images-in-python/) called "Fourier Transforms of Images in Python".